# Missing pools in Toloka

Tags: pool, toloka

When I check my old projects in Toloka, I can't find pools: the interface doesn't show them. Do you know where they are? And how do I know why a pool was archived and its archiving date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, archived pools aren't displayed in the list of project pools.

To see them:
o Open the project page.
o Click the "Show/hide filters" button at the top of the Pools table.
o In the "Status" filter, select "Archived".

You can only find out the date of pool archiving in the API. Get a list of operations with the type POOL.ARCHIVE

[Missing pools in Toloka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68681275/missing-pools-in-toloka)